# Daemon thread stopping automatically?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, python-multithreading

Here is a bit of the scenario:

File A:

```
from fileb import StatusClass

class MainClass (tk.Tk):
    #init
    ...
    self.anotherclass = StatusClass(parent, controller)

    #DOSOMESTUFF

    self._startprgram()
```

File B:

```
class StatusClass (tk.Frame):
    #init
    ...
    self.anotherclass = StatusProcess


class StatusProcess (threading.Thread):
    #init method
    self.setDaemon(True)

    def run():
        while True:
            #do stuff
```

What happens is that, depending on the run time in #DOSOMESTUFF in file A, the thread that is created stops.

If I have a few instructions it holds, but if I even add a time.sleep for a few seconds the thread also stops.
Any suggestion?

Comment: There's a lot missing from your example. I'll _assume_ that there is no `break` statement in the `#do stuff` body of your thread's main loop, but what if an exception was raised? Are you sure you would know if that happened? And would you know what exception was raised, and from where?

Comment: There is no break in the routine. Also, the code does not raise any exceptions, I only know by throwing a log `.enumerate()` to show which threads are active. For a moment it starts then simply dies.

Comment: ***"the code does not raise any exceptions"***: Prove if you see the exeption, do `int('')` in `#do stuff`. [Edit] your question and explain in detail, **why** do you use `.setDaemon(True)`?